# Parsing HTML tags into XML

Tags: java, html, xml

I’m trying to parse XML that’s embedded in the HTML file below.  Here's the detail from one of the tags:

```
           DOM<tr class="iris_table_row">
                <td style=" width:37.50%; text-align:left; " class="ta_10"><span class="ta_10">Tangible assets</span></td>
                <td style=" width:2.50%; text-align:right; " class="ta_10"><span class="ta_10">2</span></td>
                <td style=" width:30.00%; text-align:right; " class="ta_61"><ix:nonFraction contextRef="cfwd_31_03_2014" name="ns5:TangibleFixedAssets" unitRef="GBP" decimals="0" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">7,956</ix:nonFraction></td>
                <td style=" width:1.25%; " class="ta_61" />
                <td style=" width:26.25%; text-align:right; " class="ta_60"><ix:nonFraction contextRef="cfwd_31_03_2013" name="ns5:TangibleFixedAssets" unitRef="GBP" decimals="0" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">5,402</ix:nonFraction></td>
                <td style=" width:1.25%; " class="ta_60" />
                <td style=" width:1.25%; " class="ta_10" />
            </tr>
```

I’ve tried using a DOM parser in java to do this but it doesn’t recognize the XML tags.

The value of db.parse(fXmlFile) in the code below is "null".

```
File fXmlFile = new File("Prod223_1254_04903825_20140331 copy.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringComments(false);
    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(false);
    dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    System.out.println(db.parse(fXmlFile));
```

How can I get the all the tags and information into java?  Ideally I'd be able to load them into a bean.

Here is an example of the type of file I’m trying to parse.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" xmlns:ixt="http://www.xbrl.org/inlineXBRL/transformation/2010-04-20" xmlns:ixt2="http://www.xbrl.org/inlineXBRL/transformation/2011-07-31" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:xl="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:iris="http://www.iris.co.uk/ixbrl" xmlns:ns0="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/gaap/core-full/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns5="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/gaap/core/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns6="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/reports/direp/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns7="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/cd/business/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns8="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/all/types/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns9="http://xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt" xmlns:ns10="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/all/common/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns11="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/ref" xmlns:ns12="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/cd/countries/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns13="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/all/ref/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns14="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/cd/currencies/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns15="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/cd/exchanges/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns16="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/cd/languages/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns17="http://www.xbrl.org/2004/ref" xmlns:ns18="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/all/gaap-ref/2009-09-01" xmlns:ns19="http://www.xbrl.org/uk/reports/aurep/2009-09-01" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:ns20="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/uk/fr/tax/full-gaap-dpl/2013-10-01" xmlns:ns21="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/uk/fr/tax/dpl-gaap-main/2013-10-01" xmlns:ns22="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/uk/fr/tax/dpl-gaap/2013-10-01" xmlns:ns23="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/uk/fr/tax/dpl-core/2013-10-01">
<head>
    <meta name="PostingEntryNumber" content="4" />
    <meta name="PeriodRecordNumber" content="2341" />
    <meta content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta name="description" content="iXBRL report production" />
    <meta name="Mode" content="CH" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

    <title>Shortt Orthopaedics Limited - Limited company - abbreviated - 11.6</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print
        {
            hr { display:none; }
            .portraitpage
            {
                min-height:273mm;
                max-width:170mm;
            }
            .landscapepage
            {
                min-height:170mm;
                max-width:273mm;
            }
        }
        @media screen
        {
            .portraitpage
            {
                max-width:170mm;
                min-height:273mm;
                margin:12mm 20mm 12mm 20mm;
            }
            .landscapepage
            {
                max-width:273mm;
                min-height:170mm;
                margin:12mm 20mm 12mm 20mm;
            }
        }
        body{ margin:0px; font-size:1.3em; }
        td{ padding:0px; }
        div.portraitpage{ page-break-after:always; position:relative; }
        div.landscapepage{ page-break-after:always; position:relative; }
            div.header{ position:relative; }
            div.footer{ left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; text-align:center; position:absolute; }
    div.container{ position:relative; }
                    div.maintext{ width:100.00%; position:relative; }
                    div.tagged_blob{ width:100.00%; position:relative; }
                                table.iris_table{ width:100.00%; border-collapse:collapse; }
                table.iris_table_header{ width:100.00%; border-collapse:collapse; }
                table.iris_table_footer{ width:100.00%; border-collapse:collapse; }
        div.hr.iris_hr{ width:100.00%; }
            td.total_single{ border-top:thin solid black; }
            td.total_double{ border-top:double black; }
        .ta_10{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_11{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_12{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_13{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_20{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_21{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_22{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_23{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_30{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_31{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_32{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_33{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_40{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_41{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_42{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_43{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_50{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_51{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_52{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_53{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_60{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_61{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_62{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_63{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_70{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_71{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_72{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_73{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_80{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_81{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_82{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_83{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_90{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_91{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_92{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_93{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_100{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_101{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_102{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_103{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_110{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_111{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_112{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_113{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_120{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_121{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_122{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_123{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_130{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Courier New"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_131{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Courier New"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_132{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Courier New"; font-size:13px; font-weight:700; }
        .ta_133{ text-decoration:underline; color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Courier New"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_140{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Arial"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_141{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Arial"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_142{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Arial"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
        .ta_143{ color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:"Arial"; font-size:13px; font-weight:400; }
    </style>
</head>
<body xml:lang="en">
    <div style="display:none">
        <ix:header>
            <ix:hidden>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:NameAuthor" order="1" tupleRef="XBRLDocumentAuthorGrouping_Group45" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL"></ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:DescriptionOrTitleAuthor" order="2" tupleRef="XBRLDocumentAuthorGrouping_Group45" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL"></ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:UKCompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">07189486</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="CountriesHypercube_FY_31_03_2014_Set1" name="ns7:CountryFormationOrIncorporation" format="ixt2:nocontent" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" />
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="CurrenciesHypercube_FY_31_03_2014_Set2" name="ns7:PrincipalCurrencyUsedInBusinessReport" format="ixt2:nocontent" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" />
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="EntityOfficersHypercube_FY_31_03_2014_Set3" name="ns5:NameDirectorSigningAccounts" format="ixt2:nocontent" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" />
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="cfwd_31_03_2014" name="ns7:StartDateForPeriodCoveredByReport" format="ixt2:datedaymonthyear" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">1.4.13</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="cfwd_31_03_2014" name="ns7:EndDateForPeriodCoveredByReport" format="ixt2:datedaymonthyear" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">31.3.14</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="cfwd_31_03_2014" name="ns7:BalanceSheetDate" format="ixt2:datedaymonthyear" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">31.3.14</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:EntityAccountsType" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">Company accounts</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:LegalFormOfEntity" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">Private Limited Company</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:DescriptionPeriodCoveredByReport" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">FY</ix:nonNumeric>
                <ix:nonNumeric contextRef="FY_31_03_2014" name="ns7:EntityTrading" format="ixt2:booleantrue" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">true</ix:nonNumeric>
```

[stackoverflow limits body text]

Comment: If stackoverflow limits the body text, cut out the bits that are irrelevant to your question. The limit is there for a reason; you don't have to post 4 kByte of XML to get your point across. (Besides, what *is* your point? You did not specify *which* tags you want to load where in what form.)

Comment: I didn't specify which tags as I want to load all the tags.  In what form?  Well strings for string tags, etc.  Do you know how to parse HTML like this?

Comment: Asked differently, what shall be the result, the final goal of the whole operation? An HTML file? And please cut down on your post size, this will also help you set up a meaningful example.

Comment: I dont help when i got downvoted. Bad question by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a two step approach.

- Use a HTML parser to get to the embedded XML in question
- ...then use the DOM parser on the content

HTML is not always XML compliant (unless you're using XHTML which has become less fashionable). Browsers let lots of things slip like missing tags, single vs double quotes, attributes without values etc, this is probably why your site fails to parse.

Many are available.

- [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [DTD validation always takes place](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)), even when you tell it not to!

What you want to do is to create a new DTD that adds your namespace to the standard XHTML DTD; the W3 site [discusses how to acheive this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/dtd_developing.html#sec_E.4.2.), and the example they give is for MathML:

> First, define a content model module that instantiates the MathML DTD and connects it to the content model:

```
<!-- File: mathml-model.mod -->
<!ENTITY % XHTML1-math
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/dtd/mathml2.dtd" >
%XHTML1-math;

<!ENTITY % Inlspecial.extra 
     "%a.qname; | %img.qname; | %object.qname; | %map.qname; 
      | %Mathml.Math.qname;" >
```

> Next, define a DTD driver that identifies our new content model module as the content model for the DTD, and hands off processing to the XHTML 1.1 driver (for example):

```
<!-- File: xhtml-mathml.dtd -->
<!ENTITY % xhtml-model.mod
      SYSTEM "mathml-model.mod" >
<!ENTITY % xhtml11.dtd
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" >
%xhtml11.dtd;
```